# UIScreen seems to be returning the wrong sizes on some European models of iPhone

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscreen

I'm seeing very odd layouts on one of our apps with European versions of some devices. I check the UIScreen.bounds to make some basic decisions about layout: icon size and spacing for example. It works great on test devices and the simulator, but some users in the EU (France and Ireland for example) are sending us screen grabs where the layout is broken. The device seems to be sending back larger screen sizes than they have. Anyone else noticed this or found a solution?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `UIScreen.bounds` ... use the view bounds or frame -- factoring in the safe-area as needed.

Comment: it looks like that is initially wrong too. It's very hard to test as I don't have any of these devices to hand.

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences. I suspect your *"some users in the EU"* is a red-herring. These days, you should be using auto-layout / constraints (instead of calculating sizes), ***and*** the `UIScreen.bounds` won't necessarily be valid for the device / rotation / multi-tasking (split, slide-over, etc) and so on.

Comment: We are slowly moving over to swiftUI but even then we need the flexibility to change spacing according to the device size. It's a landscape only app so that solves some of the orientation issues. The only people we have issues with are people with device ids that are obscure. For everybody else with the same device it works as it should do. it's very odd.